# Find all parent's parents of a set of deeply nested child objects in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

This maybe sounds confusing but it's easy to explain. Let's say I have those 3 deeply nested models:

```
//boo.rb
class Boo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
end

//foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boo
  has_many :goos
end

//goo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Now if I got a set of Goos in `@goos`, is it possible to get all connected Foos in a lean way? I am using this atm but it's not very lean because I only get the ids in the first step and not the object themselves:

```
@goos.pluck(:foo_id)
```

And if there is a better way to do that, is there also a way to get all parents of the connected Foos? So that I have the one set of all Boos connected to the objects in `@goos`?

Hope this question is not too weird but I am not sure if there are technical terms for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works like this:

```
#Get all Foos
@foos = @goos.map(&:foo).compact.uniq

#Get all Boos
@boos = @goos.map(&:foo).map(&:boo).compact.uniq
```

Although it's not really great cause it return an array instead of an active record relation meaning I can't call `where` and `order` on it.

Edit:

If it's important for some reason to preserve the active record relation class, this is the better way:

```
#Get all Foos
@foos = Foo.where(id: @goos.map(&:foo.id).uniq)

#Get all Boos
@boos = Boo.where(id: @goos.map(&:foo).map(&:boo_id).uniq)
```